# XSLT title auto-generate

Tags: html, xml, email, xslt

I'm fairly green when it comes to XML/XSLT email builds. I cannot figure out how to properly call the "CampaignName" and place it into the  tag.

My XML is as such:

```
<KANARoot>
<EventRequest Id="" CompanyName="default" CampaignName="Statement_Notification">
<Customer  KeyField="alt_customer_id" alt_customer_id="-1" EmailAddress="customer@gmail.com" First_Name="Customer" Last_Name="Name" Address_Line1="" Address_Line2="" City="" State="" Postal_Code="">
<CustomerAttribute      Name="workOrder"/>
<CustomerAttribute      Name="soaMessageId">10</CustomerAttribute>
<CustomerAttribute      Name="accountType">R</CustomerAttribute>
<CustomerAttribute      Name="accountEsbNamespace">8448200010063009</CustomerAttribute>
<CustomerAttribute      Name="billingID">202</CustomerAttribute>
<CustomerAttribute      Name="divisionId">CAR</CustomerAttribute>
<CustomerAttribute      Name="workOrderTimestamp">2013-01-31T10:01:41.109-05:00</CustomerAttribute>
</Customer>
<Event CampaignName="Statement_Notification">
<ExternalXML>
<CustomerInfo>
<CustomerName>Customer Name</CustomerName>
<CustomerBusinessName>Customer</CustomerBusinessName>
<PaperLessFlag>Paperless</PaperLessFlag>
<CustomerEmailAddress>sandhya@gmai.com</CustomerEmailAddress>
</CustomerInfo>
<StatementInfo>
<AccountNumber>8448200000000001</AccountNumber>
<StatementCode/>
<StatementDate>01/31/2013</StatementDate>
<StatementDueDate>01/31/2013</StatementDueDate>
<StatementFromDate>01/31/2013</StatementFromDate>
<StatementToDate>01/31/2013</StatementToDate>
<AmountDue>1000.00</AmountDue>
</StatementInfo>
<DivisionInfo>
<DivisionID>CAR.202</DivisionID>
<BillingSystem>ACP</BillingSystem>
</DivisionInfo>
</ExternalXML>
</Event>
</EventRequest>
```

My XLST so far is:

```
<title><xsl:value-of select="EventRequest/Event/CampaignName" /></title>
```

But that isn't working. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`CampaignName` is an attribute, not a child element of the `Event`, so you need an XPath such as `EventRequest/Event/@CampaignName`

Comment: @MaxQuattromani glad it helped, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  You should consider marking the answer as _accepted_ using the tick mark to the left - building a track record of accepting good answers is the way to encourage people to help you with future questions.